# Error in implementing BFS to find the shortest transformation from one word to another(Word Ladder Challenge)

Tags: python-3.x, graph, undirected-graph

I am trying to implement the word ladder problem where I have to convert one word to another in shortest path possible.Obviously we can use the breadth first search (BFS) to solve it but before that we have to first draw the graph.I have implemented the concept of buckets where certain words fall under a bucket if they match the bucket type.But my graph is not implementing correctly.

The given word list is ["CAT", "BAT", "COT", "COG", "COW", "RAT", "BUT", "CUT", "DOG", "WED"]

So for each word I can create a bucket.For example for the word 'CAT', I can have three buckets _AT, C_T, CA_. Similarly I can create buckets for the rest of the words and which ever words match the bucket type will fall under those buckets.

My code for expressing the problem in graph works fine and I get a graph like this (theoritical)
[image]

Now I need to find the shortest no of operations to transform 'CAT' to 'DOG'.So I use a modified method of BFS to achieve it.It works fine when I make a sample graph of my own.For example

```
graph = {'COG': ['DOG', 'COW', 'COT'], 'CAT': ['COT', 'BAT', 'CAT', 'RAT'], 'BUT': ['CUT', 'BAT'], 'DOG': ['COG']}
```

The code works fine and I get the correct result.But if I have a huge list of words say 1500, it's not feasible to type and create a dictionary that long.So I made a function which takes those words from the list, implements the technique I dicussed above and creates the graph for me which works just fine until here.But when I try to get the shortest distance between two words, I get the following error

```
for neighbour in neighbours:
TypeError: 'Vertex' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code below

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.id = key
        self.connectedTo = {}

    # add neighbouring vertices to the current vertex along with the edge weight
    def addNeighbour(self,nbr,weight=0):
        self.connectedTo[nbr] = weight

    #string representation of the object
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " is connected to " + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

    def getConnections(self):
        return self.connectedTo.keys()

    def getId(self):
        return self.id

    def getWeight(self,nbr):
        return self.connectedTo[nbr]

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertList = {}
        self.numVertices = 0

    def addVertex(self,key):
        self.numVertices += 1
        newVertex = Vertex(key)
        self.vertList[key] = newVertex
        return newVertex

    def getVertex(self,n):
        if n in self.vertList:
            return self.vertList[n]
        else:
            return None

    def addEdge(self,f,t,cost=0):
        if f not in self.vertList:
            nv = self.addVertex(f)

        if t not in self.vertList:
            nv = self.addVertex(t)

        self.vertList[f].addNeighbour(self.vertList[t],cost)

    def getVertices(self):
        return self.vertList.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.vertList.values())

# I have only included few words in the list to focus on the implementation
wordList = ["CAT", "BAT", "COT", "COG", "COW", "RAT", "BUT", "CUT", "DOG", "WED"]

def buildGraph(wordList):
    d = {} #in this dictionary the buckets will be the keys and the words will be their values
    g = Graph()
    for i in wordList:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            bucket = i[:j] + "_" + i[j+1:]
            if bucket in d:
                #we are storing the words that fall under the same bucket in a list 
                d[bucket].append(i)
            else:
                d[bucket] = [i]

    # create vertices for the words under the buckets and join them
    #print("Dictionary",d)
    for bucket in d.keys():
        for word1 in d[bucket]:
            for word2 in d[bucket]:
                #we ensure same words are not treated as two different vertices
                if word1 != word2:
                    g.addEdge(word1,word2)
    return g

def bfs_shortest_path(graph, start, goal):
    explored = []
    queue = [[start]]
    if start == goal:
        return "The starting node and the destination node is same"
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path[-1]
        if node not in explored:
            neighbours = graph[node] # it shows the error here
            for neighbour in neighbours:
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(neighbour)
                queue.append(new_path)
                if neighbour == goal:
                    return new_path

            explored.append(node)

    return "No connecting path between the two nodes"

# get the graph object
gobj = buildGraph(wordList)
# just to check if I am able to fetch the data properly as mentioned above where I get the error (neighbours = graph[node])
print(gobj["CAT"]) # ['COT', 'BAT', 'CUT', 'RAT']
print(bfs_shortest_path(gobj, "CAT", "DOG"))
```

To check neighbouring vertices of each vertex, we can do

```
for v in gobj:
    print(v)
```

The output is obtained as below which correctly depicts the graph above.

```
CAT is connected to ['COT', 'BAT', 'CUT', 'RAT']
RAT is connected to ['BAT', 'CAT']
COT is connected to ['CUT', 'CAT', 'COG', 'COW']
CUT is connected to ['COT', 'BUT', 'CAT']
COG is connected to ['COT', 'DOG', 'COW']
DOG is connected to ['COG']
BUT is connected to ['BAT', 'CUT']
BAT is connected to ['BUT', 'CAT', 'RAT']
COW is connected to ['COT', 'COG']
CAT is connected to ['COT', 'BAT', 'CUT', 'RAT']
```

What could be going wrong then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out the issue.The problem was in this line of code

```
neighbours = graph[node]
```

Basically it is trying the fetch the neigbours for the particular node.So it needs to access the `vertList` dictionary declared as an attribute for the `Graph` class.So for an object to access the dictonary value, one has to implement a `__getitem__` special method.So I declare this under the `Graph` class as follows

```
# returns the value for the key which will be an object    
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.vertList[key]
```

Now `graph[node]` will be able to fetch the object representation of the node since the value of `vertList` dictionary is a vertex object (`vertList` stores vertex name as key and vertex object as value) .So I have to explicitly tell it to fetch the object's neighbours and not the object itself.So I can call the `getConnections()` method under the `Vertex` class which further calls the `connectedTo` attribute to get the neighbour objects for the particular vertex object. (`connectedTo` dictionary has the vertex object as the key and edge weight as the value.)

So now those neighbour objects will have their own ids which I can access and use it for the BFS operation.The below line is the modified code (under the `bfs_shortest_path` method) which does the above work.

```
if node not in explored:
    neighbours = [x.id for x in graph[node].getConnections()]
```

Now I get the list of the neigbours for the particular node and use it.The rest of the code stays the same.